# Check if user is operator using Bot::BasicBot

Tags: perl, bots, irc

I'm using [`Bot::BasicBot`](http://search.cpan.org/~hinrik/Bot-BasicBot-0.89/lib/Bot/BasicBot.pm) to make a simple irc bot in perl. How do I check if a given user is a channel operator when receiving a message? The user that sent the message is `$message->{who}`, but how can I check the operator status of that user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[https://metacpan.org/pod/Bot::BasicBot#channel_data](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bot%3a%3aBasicBot#channel_data)

```
channel_data
```

Takes a channel names as a parameter, and returns a hash of hashes. The keys are the nicknames in the channel, the values are hashes containing the keys `"voice"` and `"op"`, indicating whether these users are `voiced` or `opped` in the channel.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at it now, I see that there is POE::Component::IRC::State object underlying it, which I can get with pocoirc. I think what I will do is use `$bot->pocoirc->is_operator($message->{who})`.